# Searching a word from a specific dictionary file in sdcv(console version of Stardict offline dictionary)

Tags: bash, command-line, dictionary

I have recently installed **sdcv**(console version of Stardict offline dictionary) and have installed 5-6 dictionary files as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191125/is-there-an-offline-command-line-dictionary)

Whenever i search any word, using `sdcv hello` or `sdcv cat` , it **gives the meaning of the word from all the dictionary files, on the console which clutters up the screen**.

**How can I search the word from a specific dictionary file**, eg: I wish to see cat in the usual english context, so how do i search in *stardict-oald-2.4.2*(file for oxford english dictionary) and if I wish to search cat in the linux context, how do i search using the linux dictionary file alone(*stardict-xfardic-gnu-linux-2.4.2*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-u` option:

> -u --use-dict filename
>           for search use only dictionary with this bookname

To search for a keyword in a specific dictionary create several aliases, for example `def` for general English, `defl` for Linux etc. Like this:

```
$ alias def="sdcv -u WordNet"
$ alias defl="sdcv -u 'GNU/Linux English-English Dictionary'"
```

Alias usage:

```
$ def sudo
Found 10 items, similar to sudo.
0)WordNet-->sudor
1)WordNet-->judo
2)WordNet-->kudos
3)WordNet-->ludo
4)WordNet-->Sidon
5)WordNet-->sodom
6)WordNet-->Sudan
7)WordNet-->Sudra
8)WordNet-->suds
9)WordNet-->sudsy
Your choice[-1 to abort]: ^C
$ defl sudo
Found 1 items, similar to sudo.
-->GNU/Linux English-English Dictionary
-->sudo

Provides limited super user privileges to specific users. Sudo is a program designed to allow a sysadmin to give limited root privileges to users and log root activity.  The basic philosophy is to give as few privileges as possible but still allow people to get their work done. From Debian 3.0r0 APT http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Dictionary/
```

You don't pass a path to dictionary as an argument tu `-u` but a bookname that is written in .ifo file. For example:

```
$ cat /usr/share/stardict/dic/stardict-xfardic-gnu-linux-2.4.2/xfardic-gnu-linux.ifo
StarDict's dict ifo file
version=2.4.2
wordcount=16694
idxfilesize=256945
bookname=GNU/Linux English-English Dictionary
author=Binh Nguyen
website=http://www.xfardic.org
description=Made by Hu Zheng.
date=2007.6.5
sametypesequence=m
```

Comment: great, i'll check this out

Comment: I made an alias for the file path like this `alias eng='/usr/share/stardict/dic/stardict-oald-2.4.2'` and then tried to use `sdcv -u eng`, but this doesn't work. I'm new to linux and would love to know what i'm doing wrong. thanks

Comment: see updated answer